# Flip a biased coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A & B have a biased coin that has a probability of P for heads. A flips the coin 20 times and B flips 40 times. What is the probability that A observed 10 heads from his 20 flips, given that they got a total of 20 heads from the 60 total flips. Does this probability depend on the value of p

> $\frac{(^{40}C_{10} * p^{10} * (1-p)^{30}) * (^{20}C_{10} * p^{10} * (1-p)^{10})} {^{60}C_{20} * p^{20} * (1-p)^{40}} $ and it does not depend on p as p and 1-p cancels out.

is my solution correct?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the condition.  You know they got a combined $20$...figure out the probability of that and then compute what portion of that is explained by the precise case you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we know is that $20$ heads are distributed among $60$ flips. Since the probability of heads is fixed, those $20$ heads are equally likely to occur anywhere in the string of $60$ flips, i.e., any string of $20$ heads and $40$ tails is equally likely.

Thus, we're really asking the probability of drawing $10$ $H$'s in $20$ draws, without replacement, from a bag containing $20$ $H$'s and $40$ $T$'s.

This is a hypergeometric distribution problem. The desired probability is given by:

$$\frac{\binom{20}{10}\binom{40}{10}}{\binom{60}{20}}$$

The underlying probability $p$ doesn't enter into it.